# Zip codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new using framework CodeIgniter. I create a download zip. the process has been done. but after download pop up. It not showing the full name of the zip.

Below is the code

> Below is the code of the controller.

```
            // Initialize archive object
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $zipFileName = $this->session->userdata('user_id')."-".$data['batch_name']."-".date("Ymd").".zip";

            $zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

                    // Create recursive directory iterator
                    // @var SplFileInfo[] $files 
            $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

            foreach ($files as $name => $file){

                        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
                if (!$file->isDir()){

                            // Get real and relative path for current file
                    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                    $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

                            // Add current file to archive
                    $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);

                }

            }

                    // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
            $zip->close();

                    // or however you get the path
            $yourfile = FCPATH.$zipFileName;

            $file_name = basename($yourfile);

            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($yourfile));

            readfile($yourfile);

            // unlink($yourfile);

            // delete_files(FCPATH.'assets/files/downloads/'.$this->session->userdata('user_id').'/sapFormat', TRUE);

    }
```

The ouput is in the image.

[image: Output image.]

What is should be.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
```

to

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
```

as you are having special characters in your `$filename` like space etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the filename with double-quotes.

For example, the output must look like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1-PATCH BSAM-20200127.zip"
```

With a variable, the following should work:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
```